# qt gui project in eclipse using qt plugin

Tags: c++, eclipse, qt, user-interface, windows-7

So I have made a new qt gui project, gave it a name and right after it was created i received this error:

`"No default QT version is set.Open the QT page in the preferences dialogue and add a QT version."`

I open the preferences dialog,click add ,but when i have to give the path for the bin and the include files,i can't find any where my QT SDK is installed.

I installed qt sdk 1.2.1,and qt eclipse integration 1.6.1.

Where are those paths installed in qt sdk?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are asked to add a Qt version. To do so, go to the eclipse preferences, switch to the Qt page and click on "Add...".

You will then be asked the binary path (of the Qt binary files for the build process, these are for example qmake, moc, ...) and include path (where the Qt header files are stored).

Browse for your Qt installation path and select the subdirectories **bin** and **include** respectively.

If you *don't know* where Qt has been installed to, try to launch the Qt command line (not the Windows default command line) from your Windows start menu and type:

`qmake -v`

The output should then look similar to this:

```
QMake version ...
Using Qt version ... in C:\Qt\...\lib
```

Your **bin** path sould then be at `C:\Qt\...\bin`; the **include** path at `C:\Qt\...\include`.

Then accept the assistant dialog and select this version as the default version by clicking on the "Default" button. Then retry to build your project.

Comment: well i understood that in the first place.but i don't have such folders.

Comment: Which path did you install Qt SDK to? I think you have been asked that path in the setup.

Comment: I guess the default path is `C:\qt\4.8.1\...`

Comment: You could also try to open the Qt command line from the start menu (not the default windows command line), then type `qmake -v`. The output should then show something like: `Using Qt version 4.8.1 in C:\Qt\4.8.1\lib`. The bin folder will then be in the parent folder of the lib folder.